# Any large databases of IR Spectra that you are able to download many spectra in bulk

Tags: ir-spectroscopy, databases, machine-learning

I am currently working on a machine learning project, in which I need access to many IR spectra, the more the better, in order to build a classifier that will used some unsupervised learning in order to work out the functional groups present in the IR Spectrum. The only databases I have found so far do not have such a feature. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might fit better on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/). They already have a good couple questions about database requests/machine learning

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not really a site to give outside resource recommendations outside of our master list.